# Get extreme X and Y values in angular highcharts (ng-highcharts)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm using `ng-highcharts` to draw a stock chart containing 3 series. I'm using a navigator to zoom. What I want to know is how can I get the extreme `y` values of each series when

1. drawing the graph and
2. when changing the graph using navigator.

I know to call event on `x-axis` when navigator event happens. But have no idea how to get the extreme values.

PS: **Not using jQuery**

Comment: So you are using afterSetExtremes method? I think that you should be able to get extremes using this.min and this.max; You may also use getExtremes() method for getting extremes of your axis: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes

Comment: That thing is fixed by myself. @GrzegorzBlachliński May I know how to get the chart object or extreme values when the graph is just loaded. I've tried `load` event on `chart`. but it's not working

Comment: I think it may be some problem with ng-highcharts in this case. Look at this github topic: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/203